# How can I render multiple Javascripts on the index page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

how can I render javascript from action1, action2 and action3 in the index.html.erb ???
in the index action, I need to run these actions and after they are done, I need to notify that they were done using an alert... but rails does not render more than once, is there a work around?

## controller:

```
def index
  action1
  action2
  action3
end


def action1
  # do some process
  #send a javascript alert "action1 finished" (but display that alert in the index)
end

def action2
  # do some process
  #send a javascript alert "action2 finished" (but display that alert in the index)
end
def action3
  # do some process
  #send a javascript alert "action3 finished" (but display that alert in the index)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to render more than once in controller, while your structure sounds appealing as it's clean and well constructed.

There are two solutions depends on how complex your logics in action1, action2...

#### Simple way: Use partial

```
# FoosController
def index
  @foos = Foo.scoped
end

# app/views/foos/index.html.erb
render partial: 'partial_1', locals: { local_1: @foos.local_1}
render partial: 'partial_2', locals: { local_2: @foos.local_2}
```

#### Using Cells gem

https://github.com/apotonick/cells

The controller code is the same. The difference is you `render_cell` instead of partial in index view. And then you can add complex logic in Cells mini controller

#### Conclusion

If the logic in controller is not that complex I would prefer partial. Cells would be better for widget like segments.

Comment: what I want is somehow alert "action1 finished", "action2 finished", "action 3 finished"    -- all in the index.html.erb

Comment: sorry, I will reformulate the question, for better understanding

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos, no need to update. I understand your concern as I thought same before but I ended up using partial.

Comment: so will the javascript alert only after each action is finished?

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos, in partials.

Comment: where is action1, action2 and action3 ?

Comment: these processes take a while, I want to send the corresponding javascript only after they are completed